How to extend only MultipleSelection adapter in select2?
In my project I'm using select2 for single selection and multiple selection dropdowns. I would like to extend only the MultipleSelection adapter for select2.
Inside my js file i have:
selectElement.select2({
  placeholder: options.placeholder,
  multiple: options.multiSelect,
  closeOnSelect: !options.multiSelect,
  maximumSelectionLength: options.maxSelections,
  selectionAdapter: $.fn.select2.amd.require("customMultiselectAdapter")
});

and my custom adapter looks like:
$.fn.select2.amd.define("customMultiselectAdapter", [
    "jquery",
    "select2/utils",
    "select2/selection/multiple",
    "select2/selection/eventRelay"
],
function ($, MultipleSelection, EventRelay, Utils)
{
    function CustomAdapter ($element, options)
    {
        MultipleSelection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

        this.options = options;
    }

    Utils.Extend(CustomAdapter, MultipleSelection);

    CustomAdapter.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
        var $container = $(
            '<li class="select2-custom-selection__choice">' +
            '<span class="select2-custom-selection__text"></span>' +
            '<button class="select2-custom-selection__btn--remove"><span class="select2-custom-selection__icon"></span></button>' +
            '</li>'
        );

        return $container;
    };

    return Utils.Decorate(CustomAdapter, EventRelay);
});

But now it executes the CustomAdapter.prototype.selectionContainer for both, the single selection and multiple selection case.
Thanks for any help
